# Creating pygame.Rect fails when using keyword arguments

Tags: python, pygame

I have a working program, but if I change my pygame.Rect() constructor / function, then my program crashes.

If you look at the code below, then

```
button_rect1 = pygame.Rect(450, 300, 100, 100)
```

works just fine. But if I change it to

```
button_rect2 = pygame.Rect(left = 450, top = 300, width = 100, height = 100)
```

then I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\_python_projects\workshift_logger\component_testing.py", line 31, in <module>
    button_rect = pygame.Rect(left = 450, top = 300, width = 100, height = 100)
TypeError: Argument must be rect style object
[Finished in 0.7s with exit code 1]
```

The only thing I've changed is adding names to the arguments. Why can't I do this, and how can I change my code so I can name my arguments (I want to name them for clarity's sake - in some API's rectangles are (x, y, width, height), in others they are (x1, y1, x2, y2)):

Here's a minimal, standalone example:

```
##### Imports ######
import pygame


##### Settings #####
window_width  = 1000
window_height =  600


##### Program #####
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height))

button_rect1 = pygame.Rect(450, 300, 100, 100)                                 # This works
button_rect2 = pygame.Rect(left = 450, top = 300, width = 100, height = 100)   # This doesn't work
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you can't do this because it doesn't have this functionality. Keep it as is `pygame.Rect(450, 300, 100, 100)`

Comment: Is it Python that doesn't support named arguments for __init__ methods? Or is it Pygame that doesn't support this?

Comment: Rect constructor takes a lot of different arguments. So signature is probably *args,**kwargs.

Comment: Ohh, I see. That makes sense.

Comment: it doesn't support named arguments for this init. It can be run also with different values - like tuples `Rect( (450, 300), (100, 100) )` or other rect `Rect( other_rect )`

Comment: it has something to do with signature that contains a `/`: `__init__(self, /, *args, **kwargs)`. Also structures directly map to C SDL counterparts, not much parameter naming in C.

Answer (score 2):

Keyword arguments support for, at least, some was added in 2.0.0 as per the official [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html).

> Changed in pygame 2.0.0: Added support for keyword arguments.

So Pygame does support keyword arguments (if the version is >= 2.0.0) .. at least for some.

As per the documentation [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html), you can instantiate a Rect using three methods:

> ```
> Rect(left, top, width, height) -> Rect
> Rect((left, top), (width, height)) -> Rect
> Rect(object) -> Rect
> ```

May be, still, there is not a support for the pygame.rect even though there is support for pygame.draw.rect ... in terms of keyword arguments. May be your version is less than 2.0.0

Not sure if I was able to answer the question.